# Pillow - Gaussian blur has a black color instead of blurring the image color

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a blur between two stitched images. To paste one image next to the other, I'm doing:

```py
stitched_images = Image.new('RGBA', (im_composite.width * 2, im_composite.height))
stitched_images.paste(im_composite, (0, 0))
stitched_images.paste(im_composite, (im_composite.width, 0))
```

The ideia is to blur the area where both images meet, like so:

[screenshot of two identical images one after another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u1kf.jpg)

What I tried is to create a mask, draw a rectangle from the edges of the first image plus some padding, then blur said mask and paste the final image applying the mask with the rectangle, here's the code:

```py
mask = Image.new("L", stitched_images.size, 255)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.rectangle(((im_composite.width-5, 0), (im_composite.width+5, im_composite.height)), fill=0)
blurred_mask = mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(2))
result = Image.new("RGBA", stitched_images.size)
result.paste(stitched_images, mask=blurred_mask)
result.show()
```

The blur is being applied, however, instead of blurring out the colors in the image, is just blurring a black background, as can be seen below:

The result is:

[screenshot of two identical images one after another with a black blur where the two images meet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWy6F.png)

I've tried a few variations of the mask but none actually worked. Sometimes the final image resulted in only showing the area of the blur with the image colors, but not the rest of the image.

Comment: Please make sure your example is complete and runnable. That means including your images (or links to them) and complete code as well as a rough mock-up of how the result should look. Thank you.